# How to emit signal when the label text change?

Tags: c++, linux, forms, qt

I have 3 forms (main form, password form and menu form). The user clicks menu to open menu form, but before the menu form shows, the password form display to authenticate the user. He could display RFID card or enter his Id and password.

When he puts his card the socket notifier in main form recieved the RFID card data and it send to active form (my active form is password form). So the main form send card data to `lblrfid`:

```
if(f->windowTitle()=="PassDialog")
{
    QLabel* lbl = f->findChild<QLabel*>("lblRFID");
    //mf->processData(output);
    lbl->setText(output);
    return;
}
```

in password form I have a slot to authenticate the RFID card data and open menu form if the card is valid.

```
void MyDialog::AcceptCard()
{
    QString output=ui->lblRFID->text();
    bool st=database->checkPassword(NULL,output,"1");
    //this user is valid to go to menu page
    //s/he is admin
    if(st)
    {
        this->close();
        menu *m=new menu();
        m->showFullScreen();
    }
}
```

I want to call `AcceptCard` after the label text changed.
How can I do that?

Comment: Well you're the one changing the label... why don't you do something when you change the label?

Comment: the post is edited.

Comment: @MHM It is still not clear why can't you do what you need right after `lbl->setText(output);`.

Comment: after change the lbl text I want to close the password dialog and open menu form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided code is not the best variant of using forms...

I think password form is created in main from code? Am I correct?

Here is an example of better code (not the best of cource):

**Code can contain errors! Have no ability to check it now!**

### mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "mydialog.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void showPasswordDialog();
    void gotRFID(QString output);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    MyDialog *passwordDialog;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

### mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::showPasswordDialog()
{
    passwordDialog = new MyDialog(this);
    passwordDialog->show();
}

void MainWindow::gotRFID(QString output)
{
    if (!passwordDialog) {
        showPasswordDialog();
    }
    passwordDialog->setRFID(output);
}
```

### mydialog.h

```
#ifndef MYDIALOG_H
#define MYDIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class MyDialog;
}

class MyDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MyDialog();

public slots:
    void AcceptCard();
    void setRFID(QString data);

private:
    Ui::MyDialog *ui;
};

#endif // MYDIALOG_H
```

### mydialog.cpp

```
#include "mydialog.h"
#include "ui_mydialog.h"

MyDialog::MyDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MyDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
}

MyDialog::~MyDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MyDialog::AcceptCard()
{
    QString output=ui->lblRFID->text();
    bool st=database->checkPassword(NULL,output,"1");
    //this user is valid to go to menu page
    //s/he is admin
    if (st)
    {
        this->close();
        menu *m=new menu();
        m->showFullScreen();
    }
}

void MyDialog::setRFID(QString data)
{
    ui->lblRFID->setText(data);
    AcceptCard();
}
```

**EDIT**

You can cast `f` to `MyDialog`

```
if(f->windowTitle()=="PassDialog")
{
    MyDialog *tempDialog = qobject_cast<MyDialog*>(f);
    tempDialog->setRFID(output);
    return;
}
```

Comment: really thanks. but my main problem is here: when the password dialog is open, then the user puts his card. In main form the card data read . How can I access the child form slots from main form when the child form is open.I mean I cant create new instance of the form that it was open. In your code you used : 'passwordDialog->setRFID(output);' . when the dialog is open how can I access setRFID?

Comment: If you create `void setRFID(QString data);` public function or slot in MyDialog, you can access in anytime if you have pointer to this dialog.
You can cast `f` to `MyDialog` in your code.
`if(f->windowTitle()=="PassDialog")
{
    MyDialog *tempDialog = qobject_cast<MyDialog*>(f);
    tempDialog->setRFID(output);
}`

Comment: really thanks. `MyDialog *tempDialog = qobject_cast<MyDialog*>(f);` this line is help me so much.